# Access Violation when assigning string in InitNode event of TVirtualStringTree

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-2009, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

The given code which works without any problems in Delphi 2007. However in Delphi 2009 I am getting an exception.

> Access violation shows read of address $00000000.

The problem exists only when assigning string, it works for numbers.

Also, when I am assigning `Data.Text` manually via the debugger options I am getting no AV - it works.

Honestly I am lost, anyone could help me with this please?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, VirtualTrees, StdCtrls;

type
  TTest = record
    Text: String;
    Number: Integer;
  end;
  PTest = ^TTest;

type
  TTestArray = array of TTest;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    VirtualStringTree1: TVirtualStringTree;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure VirtualStringTree1InitNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; ParentNode,
      Node: PVirtualNode; var InitialStates: TVirtualNodeInitStates);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  TestArray: array of TTest;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(TestArray, 1);
  TestArray[0].Text := 'test';
  TestArray[0].Number := 12345;
  VirtualStringTree1.AddChild(VirtualStringTree1.RootNode, @TestArray[0]);

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VirtualStringTree1.NodeDataSize := SizeOf(TTest);

end;

procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1InitNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  ParentNode, Node: PVirtualNode; var InitialStates: TVirtualNodeInitStates);
var
  Data: PTest;
  NodeData: PPointer;
begin
  Data := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  NodeData := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  Data.Number := PTest(NodeData^)^.Number;
  Data.Text := PTest(NodeData^)^.Text; //crash here!
end;

end.
```

Comment: Just Guys? I know I am in a minority, but do you have to rub it in? :-))

Comment: @Marjan In American speak guys is usually said in a gender neutral fashion. That said, if that really is what Wodzu looks like then I would just accept whatever he/she/it wants to call you. Doesn't look like the sort of creature one wants to get on the wrong side of!

Comment: @David: yeah, I know, it just caught my eye and I couldn't resist the urge to comment. Must be because I was a little grumpy as I had overslept because I forgot to re-activate my alarm clock after a long weekend... (You did notice the smiley, didn't you?) But you are right, if Wodzu is anything like his avatar, I will try not to ruffle his hair :-)

Comment: Haha, guys!;) I am very friendly and easy to tame person, belive me;)

Comment: What else could you expect? Your code was *specially designed to crash*, and the reasons have nothing to do with Virtual TreeView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `AddChild(..., @TestArray[0])`, you're only initializing the *first four bytes* of the node's data. That's the `Text` field. The `Text` field holds a pointer to a `TTest` structure. It's *supposed* to hold a `string` reference.

The `GetNodeData` function returns a pointer to the node's data. The tree control has allocated a `TVirtualNode` record, and immediately after that, in consecutive memory, it has allocated `NodeDataSize` bytes for you to use, and `GetNodeData` returns the address of that space. You're supposed to treat that as a pointer to a `TTest` structure. And you do, for some of your code. It looks like you're trying to skirt the limitation that only the first four bytes of the structure get initialized when you call `AddChild`. (I can't say I recommend that. There are other ways to associate data with a node that don't require so much type punning.)

You assign `Data` correctly for the way the node data is supposed to be used. You assign `NodeData` correctly for what it *really* holds at the time of initialization — a pointer to a pointer to a `TTest` structure. You correctly dereference `NodeData` to read the `Number` field, and you also *read* the `Text` field correctly. However, the `Data.Text` field can't be overwritten the way you have it:

```
Data.Text := PTest(NodeData^)^.Text;
```

The `Data.Text` field doesn't current hold a valid `string` value, but `string` variables are *required* to hold valid values at all times (or at least all times where there's a possibility they'll be read or written). To assign a `string` variable, the program increments the reference count of the new value and decrements the reference count of the old one, but since the "old value" in this case isn't really a `string`, there's no valid reference count to decrement, and even if there were, the memory at that location couldn't be freed anyway — it belongs to `TestArray`.

There's a way around this, though. Copy the string in two steps. First, read the value from `NodeData.Text` into a spare `string` variable. Once you do that, you have no need for `NodeData` anymore, so you can overwrite the value it points to. If you set it to all-bits-zero, then you'll implicitly overwrite `Data.Text` as well, and with the value of an empty string. At that point, it's safe to overwrite *as a `string` variable*:

```
tmp := PTest(NodeData^)^.Text;
PTest(NodeData^) := nil;
Data.Text := tmp;
```

Another way around this is to re-arrange the order of the fields in the node data. Put the `Integer` field first, and the initialize `Data.Number` last instead of `Data.Text`. `Integer` values are always safe to overwrite, no matter their contents.

Whatever you do, make sure you *finalize* the record in the `OnFreeNode` event:

```
var
  Data: PTest;
begin
  Data := Sender.GetNodeData;
  Finalize(Data^);
end;
```

That makes sure the `string` field gets its reference count reduced, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you Rob for your time and excellent answer. I figured out the trick with reordering the record fields. But I have two out of curiosity qyestions: 1. Why I can setup Data.Text in the debugger and it works? 2. Why my example works without this problems under 2007?, and it works since few years... Thanks.

Comment: 1. I don't know what that means. 2. Strings and dynamic arrays used to have the same structure, so when the RTL looked at the pointer to `TestArray[0]` and treated it like a `string`, it found the reference count and the other memory information in the same place. When it thought it was reducing the reference count of the string, it was actually reducing that of the dynamic array. As of Delphi 2009, strings have some more data fields where previously they just had length and reference count, the same as dynamic arrays. Your code has always been wrong; you just never noticed before.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the point here. You have already inited your node on button's click event, so there is no need to use `OnInitNode` to init it additionally. What you need is probably use `OnGetText` to display your data. E.g.:

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1GetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
var
  Data: PTest;
begin
  Data := PTest(Sender.GetNodeData(Node)^);

  CellText := Data.Text;
end;
```

Comment: no, that is not true. AddChild raises OnInit event, and the pointer passed by AddChild method is used for the initialization of the node in the OnInit event.

Comment: @Wodzu That's correct but OnInitNode event is basically used for initializing your data structure. In your case you don't need that because you've already filled your array on button click. OnInitNode is useful when you just set RootNodeCount to specific value to the tree. Then it calls this method automatically for you. I suggest you to read some TVirtualStringTree documentation. P.S. If you use AddChild it is always a good idea to set newly added node's state to vsInitialized just to be sure that the tree will call OnFreeNode event to all nodes.